# Unique identifier for ratios with tolerance

Tags: python, string, algorithm, hash, rounding

I have some data that contains ratios of 5 elements `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`, `'e'`, which looks something like this:

```
data = [
    {'a': 0.197, 'b': 0.201, 'c': 0.199, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.201},
    {'a': 0.624, 'b': 0.628, 'c': 0.623, 'd': 0.625, 'e': 0.750},
    {'a': 0.192, 'b': 0.203, 'c': 0.200, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.203},
    {'a': 0.630, 'b': 0.620, 'c': 0.625, 'd': 0.623, 'e': 0.752},
]
```

I would like to hash each ratio data (represented as dict) into a string that can be used as a unique identifier for ratios with a tolerance. For example, with a tolerance of 0.1 for the ratio of each element, the expectation is that the first and third dicts should have the same identifier, and the second and fourth dicts should have the same identifier. This is easy to do if one just wants to compare if two ratio data are within the tolerance, but I am not sure how create unique identifiers.

Edit: I am looking for some rounding method, instead of completely arbitrary hashing.

Comment: What should be the output for an input like `[{'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.4}, {'a': 0.133, 'b': 0.433}, {'a': 0.167, 'b': 0.467}, {'a': 0.2, 'b': 0.5}, {'a': 0.233, 'b': 0.533}]`?

Comment: @mozway Something like `['a0.15b0.45', 'a0.20b0.50', 'a0.15b0.45', 'a0.20b0.50']`?

Comment: Did you mean `['a0.15b0.45', 'a0.15b0.45', 'a0.15b0.45', 'a0.20b0.50']`? So these are simple bins. In this case two values that are less than 0.1 apart but on two different sides of the bins would have different hashes. I guess @Stef's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply flooring and concatenating?

```py
data = [     {'a': 0.197, 'b': 0.201, 'c': 0.199, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.201},     {'a': 0.624, 'b': 0.628, 'c': 0.623, 'd': 0.625, 'e': 0.750},     {'a': 0.192, 'b': 0.203, 'c': 0.200, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.203},     {'a': 0.630, 'b': 0.620, 'c': 0.625, 'd': 0.623, 'e': 0.752}, ]

def hashwithtol(datum, abstol=0.1):
    return ','.join(
        str(int(datum[k] // abstol))
        for k in 'abcde'
    )

def groupby_hashwithtol(data, abstol=0.1):
    groups = {}
    for datum in data:
        groups.setdefault(hashwithtol(datum, abstol), []).append(datum)
    return groups

for abstol in (1, 0.1, 0.01):
    print(f'Abs tol = {abstol}')
    groups = groupby_hashwithtol(data, abstol)
    print(*(f'{k}: {g}' for k,g in groups.items()), sep='\n')
    print()
```

```
Abs tol = 1
0,0,0,0,0: [{'a': 0.197, 'b': 0.201, 'c': 0.199, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.201}, {'a': 0.624, 'b': 0.628, 'c': 0.623, 'd': 0.625, 'e': 0.75}, {'a': 0.192, 'b': 0.203, 'c': 0.2, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.203}, {'a': 0.63, 'b': 0.62, 'c': 0.625, 'd': 0.623, 'e': 0.752}]

Abs tol = 0.1
1,2,1,2,2: [{'a': 0.197, 'b': 0.201, 'c': 0.199, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.201}]
6,6,6,6,7: [{'a': 0.624, 'b': 0.628, 'c': 0.623, 'd': 0.625, 'e': 0.75}, {'a': 0.63, 'b': 0.62, 'c': 0.625, 'd': 0.623, 'e': 0.752}]
1,2,2,2,2: [{'a': 0.192, 'b': 0.203, 'c': 0.2, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.203}]

Abs tol = 0.01
19,20,19,20,20: [{'a': 0.197, 'b': 0.201, 'c': 0.199, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.201}]
62,62,62,62,74: [{'a': 0.624, 'b': 0.628, 'c': 0.623, 'd': 0.625, 'e': 0.75}]
19,20,20,20,20: [{'a': 0.192, 'b': 0.203, 'c': 0.2, 'd': 0.202, 'e': 0.203}]
62,61,62,62,75: [{'a': 0.63, 'b': 0.62, 'c': 0.625, 'd': 0.623, 'e': 0.752}]
```

- If you prefer rounding to flooring, then you can replace `int(datum[k] // abstol)` with `int(round(datum[k] / abstol))`.
- With the examples above you can notice that 0.199 and 0.2 don't get put in the same bin, because 0.199 is floored down to 0.1. Using rounding instead of flooring wouldn't fix this issue, just move the issue to different numbers; for instance 0.149 would be rounded down to 0.1 while 0.150 would be rounded up to 0.2.
- If you have more than 5 values per dict and the key is starting to get way too long, you can wrap it in a call to python's builtin `hash`: `def hashwithtol(datum, abstol=0.1): return hash(','.join(str(int(datum[k] // abstol)) for k in 'abcde'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can express that condition (if I understand correctly) with some grouping function:

```
def grouping_key(dct, tolerance=0.1):
    v = dct.values()
    return hash(max(v) - min(v) <= 0.1)

[*map(grouping_key, data)]
# [1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: This would work if I have all the data. But my situation is that I have a database and I want to upload each data with a unique identifier. In the future I will upload more data, and the identifiers for the previously-uploaded data should not change. Ideally it should not be necessary to look for all historic data when uploading new data.

Comment: Also, ideally the hash should still roughly reflect the ratios

Comment: Can you provide some sample output